# Is it possible to derive some relationship $\vec E \propto \vec H$ directly from $V = I * Z$?

Tags: electromagnetism

Since $V = I * Z$ and $-\nabla V = \vec E$ is it then possible for us to say:

$$-\nabla V = -\nabla I*Z $$

So there exists some relationship

$$\vec E \propto \vec H$$

where $\vec H$ is related to $-\nabla I*Z $

But what is the meaning of $-\nabla I$ and how can we relate it to $\vec H$?

Comment: Z as in ... impedance? And what is I? That's usually used for a lumped current. Do you mean a current density $\vec{j}$? And what is $V$? Is that suppose to be a potential $\phi$?

Comment: @CuriousOne: I think it's clear that $Z$ is impedance and $V$ is electric potential.

Comment: @DanielSank: Just making sure I understand correctly that $Z$ is assumed to be a constant impedance. I can't make any sense of the further assumed proportionality of $\vec E$ and $\vec H$. Do you understand the question?

Comment: I do understand what is being asked, yes. It's not worded particularly well, unfortunately.

Comment: IllegalImmigrant: are you assuming that $E \propto H$ beacause that's true in free space plane waves, or something like that?

Comment: Hi yes...but yes I agree the "proportionality" symbol is not particularly well suited. The point is that $E$, $H$, $\eta$ ($\eta$ being the freespace impedance) are considered to be microscopic parameters and $V$, $I$, $Z$ are macroscopic parameters. Is there a trivial way to derive a relationship between these parameters?

Comment: Conventionally one would call Maxwell's equations and classical electromagnetic waves macroscopic by definition. Lumped approximations like V, I and Z are of fairly limited use because they break Lorentz invariance. The localization of electromagnetic quantities on discrete nodes does not even meet spatial homogeneity and isotropy assumptions. I am not even sure that one can model polarization properly, not to mention that the discretized systems all suffer from dispersion.

Comment: What is this $\vec{H}$ you speak of that is related to $\vec\nabla IZ$? ;-) My point is, as far as I know, there is no such relation for the magnetic field, so if that's what you meant, your question is based on a false premise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the operator $\nabla$ meaningful on $V$, you need to be thinking about potential as a function of $\mathbb{R}^3$ *i.e.* as a differentiable function of a continuously varying position. $\nabla I$ has no meaning, since $I$ is a "bulk" quantity: it is the flux of the current density through a surface. As a fluid analogy: $I$ is analogous to a volumetric flow rate through the total cross section *e.g.* of a pipe. So you're not going to get very far with exactly this approac

However, Maxwell's equations includes Ampère's law, which is

$$\nabla\times\vec{H} = \vec{J}+\epsilon\,\partial_t\vec{E}$$

where $\vec{J}$ is the current density vector. Given a surface $\mathcal{S}$, the flux $\int\,\vec{J}\cdot\,\hat{\vec{n}}\,\mathrm{d} S$ of $\vec{J}$ through $\mathcal{S}$ equals the current $I$ through $\mathcal{S}$. For linear, Ohmic conductors, $\vec{J}=\sigma\,\vec{E}$, where $\sigma$ is the material's conductivity; more generally, it is some linear operator $\mathcal{Y}_1\,\vec{E}$ of the electric field $\vec{E}$. So, for a linear, isotropic material, the right hand side of Ampère's law is a linear operation $\mathcal{Y}\,\vec{E}$ on $\vec{E}$.

So I believe the law you are groping for is:

$$\vec{E} = \mathcal{Y}^{-1}\,\nabla\times\vec{H}\stackrel{def}{=} \mathcal{Z}\,\nabla\times\vec{H}$$

For example, in a linear, resistive, Ohmic medium, $\mathcal{Y} = \sigma+i\,\omega\,\epsilon$ for monochromatic fields of frequency $\omega$, so that:

$$\mathcal{Z} = \frac{1}{\sigma+i\,\omega\,\epsilon}$$

Answer (score 1):

I can only see a dimensional argument here. Indeed the units of $\nabla I$ would be Amps/m, and Amps per metre multiplied by an impedance in Ohms will be measured in Volts/m. That's a bit tenuous - but possibly all you need.